# error: identifier "CLOCK_PER_SEC" is undefined

Tags: c, linux, unix

While executing a piece of C code in the Unix based machine I am getting an error "**error: identifier "CLOCK_PER_SEC" is undefined**"

Attached code for reference:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<time.h>
 main()
  {
   int a[10000],i,j,min,temp;
   for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
      a[i]=rand()%10000;
    }
   //The bubble Sort
   clock_t start,end;
   start=clock();
   for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
   {
    for(j=i+1;j<10000;j++)
     {
      if(a[i]>a[j])
       {
        int temp=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=temp;
       }
     }
  }
  end=clock();
  double extime=(double) (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("\n\tExecution time for the bubble sort is %f seconds\n ",extime);
}
```

Error screenshot for reference

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There aren't any `CLOCK_PER_SEC` in your code. Check for typo.

Comment: which compiler are using?

Comment: CC isn't a compiler it's a front end.

What compiler is CC using? GCC? Clang?

Comment: are you using a C or a C++ compiler? (because in C++ this macro is declared in <ctime> header)

Comment: sometimes CLOCKS_PER_SEC is named CLK_PER_SEC . try it, it may work

Comment: In the screenshot it is actually `CLOCK_PER_SEC`, which is a typo.

Comment: And the used compiler is C++. So you have to fix the typo and use ctime instead of time.h

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided above is correct. https://ideone.com/92Ifym 
 Please have a look at it.
Following statement is correct.

```
double extime=(double) (end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

but the code in snapshot has `extime=(double) (end-start)/CLOCK_PER_SEC;` 
`CLOCK_PER_SEC` is invalid identifier while `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` valid one.

Hence Answered :)
Please let us know if you see any other issue.